# Wordpress automaticly deleting my external links headers which has custom URL scheme

Tags: wordpress

I would like to use custom URL scheme in my site. (eg. yandexnavi:// or yandexmaps://). However wordpress panel automatically deleting custom headers in external links.

Is there any solution defining new headers in child-template?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed issue with kses_allowed_protocols. I hooked new protocols and my problem solved. Also thanks to mehlkelm for sharings